# Unable to use multiple foreach function from same PDO SQL query

Tags: php, pdo

I want to fetch data from SQL using PHP and display the results in multiple parts in the page using different table sections. Cant include the table inside one foreach function.
Here is the code I am using.
The `echo $row['os'];` is properly showing, but the `echo $row['brand'];` is not at all displaying.
How can I fix that ? I want to use multiple `echo $row['valuex'];` outside the SQL code section.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename", "username", "password");
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Attempt select query execution
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM phonespecs WHERE pid IN(102883,102889,102894)";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);


} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Close connection
unset($pdo);


    foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row['os'];
} 

    foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row['brand'];
} 

?>
```

Comment: the result set for the row has reached the end that's why. put the results inside an array so that you can reuse it every time you want. use like `->fetchAll()`

Comment: @Kevin, thank you kevin, it worked for me. if you can post the same comment as an answer, I will select it as answer for this question.

Comment: you need to take care of it though, if you're loading too much data it will become slow, so you might need limit and offset at some point

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kevin, the following code worked for me.

```
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM phonespecs WHERE pid IN(102883,102889,102894)";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $results = $result->fetchAll();

    


} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Close connection
unset($pdo);


    foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row['os'];
} 

    foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row['brand'];
} 

?>
```